# Optimizing time complexity of prefix searching between two lists

Tags: java, performance, time-complexity, big-o

Looking to refactor some legacy code, and I have a method that's functionally similar to the following simplified version:

```java
public static List<String> getAllPrefixedCodes(List<String> codes, List<String> prefixes) {
   var prefixedCodes = new ArrayList<String>();
   for (String code : codes) {
      for (String prefix : prefixes) {
         if (code.startsWith(prefix)) {
            prefixedCodes.add(code);
         }
      }
   }

   return prefixedCodes;
}
```

I was looking for ways to increase the speed of the method, and came across Tries in another stack overflow post somewhere. After doing some research, though they were cool so I reimplemented the method as following:

```java
public static List<String> getAllPrefixedCodes(Collection<String> codes, Collection<String> prefixes) {
   final var trie = codes.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), Function.identity(), 
                       (a, b) -> a, PatriciaTrie::new));

   return prefixes.parallelStream()
             .map(trie::prefixMap)
             .map(SortedMap::values)
             .flatMap(Collection::stream)
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

The method is much simpler to look at in my opinion, and that's a plus already for me but I'm second guessing that it's time complexity improvement. My first instinct is that it's gone from O(n^2) to O(n). After all the second method is taking O(n) to load the trie, O(m) to search prefixes with O(n)lookup thanks to the trie (from the the [apache docs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/trie/PatriciaTrie.html#put-K-V-)).

But in the second stream, I'm doing an O(n) lookup O(m) times, so I'm hitting O(n^2) anyway, correct? Is there a more efficient or intelligent way to perform this style of operation?

Comment: in case of initial implementation the estimation O(N^2) is wrong: there are two nested loops in code + loop in `code.startsWith(prefix)`

Comment: Do you care what prefix the code starts with? Or just that is has a prefix from the list? Your reduced code would indicate the latter.

Comment: Are the prefixes fixed length?

Comment: [Aho–Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm)

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Isn't start's with complexity based not not array lengths, but string lengths? The upper bound of the case in theory wouldn't change due that, correct?

Comment: @SephB No, I actually don't care what code the prefix starts with, only that the code has any of the prefix from the list. Unfortunately the prefix are not fixed length in the context of the application.

Comment: @apangin That was an extremely interesting read, I'm curious if anyone's made a strong common implementation of what's essentially a much more complex trie.